# How to filter DataRow column containing url in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, datatable, datarow

I am using below query

```
DataRow[] oFilteredRows = 
    oTrgFTPTrigList.Select($"ftpPath='{oSrcRow["ftpPath"]}' 
    and ftpUserName='{oSrcRow["ftpUserName"]}'");
```

But it fails since ftpPath is url ftp://testURL/

I need to filter and get records with same data as of source (Comparing target and source DataBases)

Comment: What exactly you are trying to do. Add it in question.

Comment: want to match the records having same ftppath and username

Comment: what is `oSrcRow` ? Are you getting any error?

Comment: Yes but i have used Uri.EscapeUriString then its working now. I had provided answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer.

I have converted data like below.

```
    string ftpPath = Uri.EscapeUriString(oSrcRow["ftpPath"].ToString());
```

Here is the full code sample.

```
public DataTable compareFTPTriggers(string targetConnectionString)
    {
        DataTable oFTPTriggerTableDiffs = new DataTable("oFTPTriggerDiffs");
        oFTPTriggerTableDiffs.Columns.Add("oFTPTriggerID");
        oFTPTriggerTableDiffs.Columns.Add("oFTPTriggerName");
        oFTPTriggerTableDiffs.Columns.Add("Comments");

        try
        {
            deFTPTrigger oSrcFTPTrigger = new deFTPTrigger(m_connectString, m_externalUserID);

            DataTable oSrcFTPTrigList = oSrcFTPTrigger.getAllFTPTriggers();

            string systemUserID = clsSettings.systemUserID(targetConnectionString);

            deFTPTrigger oTrgFTPTrigger = new deFTPTrigger(targetConnectionString, systemUserID);

            DataTable oTrgFTPTrigList = oTrgFTPTrigger.getAllFTPTriggers();

            foreach (DataRow oSrcRow in oSrcFTPTrigList.Rows)
            {
                string ftpPath = Uri.EscapeUriString(oSrcRow["ftpPath"].ToString());


                DataRow[] oFilteredRows = oTrgFTPTrigList.Select($"ftpPath= '{ftpPath}' and ftpUserName='{oSrcRow["ftpUserName"]}'");

                string sKey = $"{oSrcRow["ftpPath"]} - {oSrcRow["ftpUserName"]}";

                if (oFilteredRows.Length == 0)
                {
                    oFTPTriggerTableDiffs.Rows.Add(oSrcRow["ftpTriggerID"], sKey, "Addition");
                }
                else
                {
                    if (

                        oSrcRow["ftpPassword"].ToString() != oFilteredRows[0]["ftpPassword"].ToString() ||
                        oSrcRow["waitTime"].ToString() != oFilteredRows[0]["waitTime"].ToString() || oSrcRow["waitType"].ToString() != oFilteredRows[0]["waitType"].ToString() ||
                        oSrcRow["definitionID"].ToString() != oFilteredRows[0]["definitionID"].ToString() || oSrcRow["variableName"].ToString() != oFilteredRows[0]["variableName"].ToString() ||
                        oSrcRow["enabled"].ToString() != oFilteredRows[0]["enabled"].ToString() || oSrcRow["globalName"].ToString() != oFilteredRows[0]["globalName"].ToString()

                       )
                    {
                        oFTPTriggerTableDiffs.Rows.Add(oSrcRow["ftpTriggerID"], sKey, "Properties are different");
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           // m_oErrorProvider.writeError(ex.Message);
        }

        DataView dvSorted = oFTPTriggerTableDiffs.DefaultView;
        dvSorted.Sort = "oFTPTriggerName ASC";
        oFTPTriggerTableDiffs = dvSorted.ToTable();

        return (oFTPTriggerTableDiffs);
    }
```